# Making \cite{ref} show last name of the first author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I am trying to obtain a non-standard citation style that includes only the last name of the first author, and the year it was published. As an example at the moment I have this:

```
myref.bib

@article{Stupid1999,

author = {Styleiz Stupid and Don Knowhy},
title = {Using totally random citation styles to write a thesis},
year = {1999},
volume = {11},
pages = {232-254},
journal = {Journal of Stupid Citation Styles}

}
```

On the tex file I cite with

```
A stupid random citation style was also used by \cite{Stupid1999}
```

The output is then:

```
A stupid random citation style was also used by [Stupid and Knowhy, 1999]
```

And what I want it to be:

```
A stupid random citation style was also used by [Stupid,1999]
```

Similar outputs to this without comma would also be appreciated, I just need that it does not include any second author or et al. in the in-line citation.

Additionally, on the references part I also need the output to be like

```
    [Stupid,1999] Stupid, S., Knowhy, D., Using totally random citation 
                  styles to write a thesis. Journal of Stupid Citation 
                  Styles, 1999, vol. 11, p. 232-254
```

The important part about this output is that it needs to be in this indentation style. The order of the citation can also be (authors, year, title, rest). 
At the moment I'm using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` cause it was the only similar option, however this will not be suitable to conclude my work.

Looking forward in advance to your suggestions.

Kind regards

Example code with package list:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{utilmat}
\usepackage{margen}
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, justification=centering, format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
%raggedrigh
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{breakcites}
%\usepackage[square]{natbib}
%\usepackage{apalike}
%\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{-}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%
\usepackage[%
style=verbose
,backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
,backref=true
,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=nyt        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false 
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,giveninits=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex} 


\addbibresource{myref.bib}

\begin{document}
    A stupid random citation style was also used by \cite{Stupid1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Errors:

biblatex.sty error line 3350 Command \Rn already defined \endgroup} and multiple warnings
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you use `biblatex`?

Comment: @Bernard I'm using `bibtex` at the moment, I've tried implementing `biblatex`, however I was not even able to print the bibliography.

Comment: PLease post a minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: My problem is probably due to an incompatibility with a loaded package, I have a large amount of them, a list was added as an edit to the question page.

Comment: @samcarter Edited on the main. Tks

Comment: @JoséCardoso is the `utilmat` package available somewhere? Is it necessary to reproduce the error? Same for margen and vector

Comment: If I comment out all the package I don't have and substitute the .bib files I also don't have, your code compiles reasonable fine.

Comment: Off-topic: `\usepackage{hyperref}` should be one of the last packages you load.

Comment: Also don't load the same packages multiple times

Comment: @samcarter @Bernard I managed to find that the ultimat package was the one in conflict with biblatex. Right now my references are like this:

`[1] A. Alizadeh et al. ‘Dynamics of Ice Nucleation on Water Repellent 
      Surfaces’.
      In: Langmuir 28.6 (2012), pp. 3180{3186. issn: 0743-7463. doi: 10.1021/
      la2045256. url: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/la2045256 (cit. on
      p. 43). `

Comment: This style seems to be pretty close to what you are looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422933/36296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer has been completely reworked for `biblatex` 3.13 and `biblatex-ext`.
>
> See the edit history for the version abusing the `alphabetic` style.

Thanks to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861 it is possible to properly suppress the "et al." even in `authoryear` styles (see [Remove "et al." only from citation and maintain it in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262612/35864)). This means we can use the `authoryear` style `ext-authoryear` as basis and employ `introcite` for the labels in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=1,
  nohashothers=true, nosortothers=true,
  uniquelist=false,
  introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter I tried to apply both suggestions, however the bibliography is not printed due to a displayed error:

`The top-level auxiliary file: maint.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file maint.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file maint.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file maint.aux
(There were 3 error messages)`

Comment: @JoséCardoso You must run Biber instead of BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 (and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background).

Comment: That's exactly it. I forgot to switch to biber. It's working now! Thank you so much!!!!!!!! I'm going to input this into my main files.