Setting 'philosophy-modern' citation style: show first author's name and add 'a' or 'b' for duplicate first authors?
I am currently writing my master thesis and I am pretty new to Latex.
I would like to change the output of the citation style "philosophy classic". When I have two papers with the same first author but with different years and second authors, I get the following text:
(AuthorA and AuthorB, 2019; AuthorA and AuthorC, 2021)
Instead I wold like to only use the first author, because as the years are different, this still allows a clear distinction to be made. I would like it to appear as:
(AuthorA, 2019; AuthorA, 2021)
But there is a second scenario, in which I would like to add lower case letters. If I have two papers with the same first author, which have been published in the same year, I would like it to appear as:
(AuthorA, 2019a and AuthorA, 2019b)
Depending on the second author's name, the lowercase letter a should be used for the first author in the alphabet and b for the paper with the second author in the alphabet.
This is my example code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = philosophy-classic, sorting = nyt, backend = biber, scauthors=all, dashed = FALSE]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

\begin{document}
    Here I would like to cite two papers written by the same author, but published in different years \parencite{paper1, paper2}.
    
    Here I would like to cite two papers written by the same author, but published in the same year \parencite{paper1, paper3}.
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}

And this is my example bibfile:
@article{paper1,
    title={Title of Paper 1},
    author={AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B.},
    journal={Journal},
    volume={1},
    number={2},
    pages={5--10},
    year={2019}
}

@article{paper2,
    title={Title of Paper 2},
    author={AuthorA, A. and AuthorC, C.},
    journal={Journal},
    volume={2},
    number={3},
    pages={2--11},
    year={2021}
}

@article{paper3,
    title={Title of Paper 3},
    author={AuthorA, A. and AuthorD, D.},
    journal={Journal},
    volume={3},
    number={2},
    pages={11--30},
    year={2019}
}

I would really appreciate the help!

It is extremely uncommon just to drop author names with no mention of doing so. Often additional names are replaced with "et al.", but if just one name is replaced (i.e. if you have just two names to start with) that feels a bit meh to me and I would just show all two names to begin with.

That said, it is possible to drop names without adding "et al.", see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262612/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464317/35864 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861, but I would generally not recommend it.

Any news here? Did any of the links above help you? Did you decide not to go through with this unusual citation setup?
